# Can't add a fragment when Creating a new Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to create a wizard Like Android application, i want to Create an activity  and Two dynamic Fragments, the first one will be added when the Activity is created, and the second when the user clicks on a button in the First fragment, right now i can't even add the Fragment to the activity :

**Activity onCreate method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fragment fr  = new FragmentNumber();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fr, "number_fragment").commit();


}
```

this is my activity code, when i run this, the screen is blank.

the R.layout.activity_main refer to an empty Linear Layout, i don't want to add the fragments there because i need them to be dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : pasting more files

**activity_main.XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello from main"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

**MaicActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragmenttraining;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(android.R.id.content) != null)
    {
        Log.d("main activity", "content found");
    }

    FragmentNumber fr  = new FragmentNumber();

    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fr, "number_fragment").commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fr).commit();

}
FragmentNumber numberFragment;
FragmentFacebook facebookFragment;
public void facebookClicked(View view)
{
    numberFragment = new FragmentNumber();
    numberFragment.facebookClicked(view);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Now it's working, but the fragment is not replaced, it displays the content of the activity_main + the content of the FragmentNumber fragment even id i replace it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create your main (activity layout) file. In it, add a frame layout which will act as a container for your fragments.
2. Now create your two fragments. This involves creating two xml files that will be inflated inside your fragment's **onCreateView** method.
3. One of your fragments (the first one) should have a button that the user will be able to click. That means you must attach an onClick listener to it inside the onCreateView method after finding it by id.
4. Now create an interface inside your first fragment and add a method in it that your activity should override after implementing the interface.
5. When the user clicks that button, inside onClick method, you should call the interface method to notify the activity of the click event.
6. Inside the activity, when the method is called, create a new instance of the second fragment and add it to view by replacing the first one - or it depends on whether you are using two-pane layout in your activity  - in that case, you just add the fragment.
7. Remember to check if your fragment exists first before simply adding one to view.

I hope these steps help you.

**Sample Code**

```
public class WizardActivity extends Activity implements SecondFragment.OnButtonClickedListener
{
   private FirstFragment firstFragment;

   public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       firstFragment = new FirstFragment();

       setFragment(firstFragment, "firstFragment");
   }


   @Override
   public void loadSecondFragment()
   {
       SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();

       setFragment(secondFragment, "secondFragment");
   }

   public void setFragment(Fragment frag, String tag)
   {
       FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

       Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
       if(fragment == null)
       {
           ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, tag);
       } else {
          ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, tag);
       }

       ft.addToBackStack(null);
       ft.commit()

   }

}
```

Now the xml file for main layout.

```
<LinearLayout ........>

    <!--add whatever you need here-->

     <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now let us create one of your fragments - the first one:

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act)
    {
        super.onAttach(act);
        this.mActivity = act;

        /*Initialize whatever you need here*/
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflator inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)

    {
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ((OnButtonClickListener), mActivity).loadSecondFragment();
    }

    public interface OnButtonClickListener
    {
        void loadSecondFragment();
    }
}
```

You should be able to just create the second fragment and have it loaded in the activity when a button is clicked.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for replying, my problem  is that i can't add the Fragment to the Activity, the fragmentA contains a textview, when i add the fragment to the activity, the Fragment's onCreate is called and Fragment's view is set but it doesn't displays the main_activity textview

Comment: Please paste your main_activity.xml file with your question.

Comment: +1 for the code you just wrote, it still can't replace the main activity content with the fragmentA content, but no problem i fixed it, if you have any Links that can help me with fragments i'll be gratefull for you. Thnaks

Comment: Check this out: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/ and am willing to help you further if you need me through gmail chat. Good luck

Comment: now again i can't press the back button when am on FragmentB, i added getActionBar().setDisplay... to true but nothing.

Comment: You should override the onBackPressed() method and then pop back stack to go back to the previous location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60271/discussion-between-user1-and-eenvincible).