# Fragment not showing up in ActionBarActivity using Android 5.0 Toolbar widget

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

When I run my app, MainFragment does not show up at all in the activity extending ActionBarActivity. I did check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633743/fragments-wont-show-up-in-activity-extending-actionbaractivity), but it didn't help me resolve my problem. Here's my activity and fragment:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

I don't think I need to reference any xml here... everything was working fine until I extended ActionBarActivity instead of Activity in activity_main.xml.

EDIT: Added xml just in case:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

// There are several text views and buttons I will not add to this code, 
// but just know that this fragment isn't blank.

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2: I've done some testing and whenever I remove the toolbar from the activity_main.xml, the fragment shows up, along with no action bar (since that is the theme I have set to my app in order to use the toolbar). So here is the xml for my toolbar.xml as well, which I use in activity_main.xml. Maybe I've done something wrong for it to hide my entire fragment?

tl;dr: fragment shows when this line of code is removed from activity_main.xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

and this one in activity_main.xml:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: @HareshChhelana One of the new Android 5.0 widgets. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe have u import `appcompat v7` library properly and what is `android:minSdkVersion` in *manifest*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just opened a [bug report at AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78701). A solution I found and use for now is to call `add()` inside a `post()`.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. Thanks to everyone else who helped as well. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with rotations, presumably because the fragment is added again without the delay introduced by `post()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your getfragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager()

Like this

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
```

to

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
```

because ActionBarActivtiy is in supportpackage so you need  getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I realize this, and I should have included it in my earlier post. When I do this, I get the "cannot resolve method add(...)" error.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding in your project properties appcompact library.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I am using the appcompat v21 library for themes and the toolbar and such, so I know I have added it to the project properly.

Comment: you can do one thing got to file->new->others->tabbed activity and hit finish and see yourself the code and check it.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me get my fragment to show up, honestly.

Comment: Are you sure you have imported this like import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: and in your activity_main should look lie this <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myaidl.FragmentActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're actually NOT using v7 appcompat library, in which case your `MainActivity` should extend `FragmentActivity` instead? See also: [Fragment add or replace not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619573/fragment-add-or-replace-not-working)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setActionBar(toolbar);
  }

  ...
}
```

Or, if you're using v7 appcompat library,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I need to extend ActionBarActivity for my Toolbar.

Comment: @Fadils [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is a `subclass` of [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) .So that is not the issue.

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe you can extend your `MainActivity` by `FragmentActivity` then for the toolbar change `setSupportActionBar` to `setActionBar`

Comment: @kaushik. Thank you. I understood this. However, we should use ActionBarActivity only when we're targeting Android 2.1 and above. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe can you please post your toolbar xml too? By not showing up at all, does it mean the app is running but nothing shows up or it's not running (compile error)?

Answer (score 0):

try like this way may help you,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
        .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Same as amit's post: When I do this, I get the "cannot resolve method add(...)" error.

Answer (score 0):

First check the `import` in `MainFragment`. I'm sure it is

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

it should be `Fragment` from `support library`

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

In `MainACtivity` instead of

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
           .commit();
}
```

Use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
     .commit();
```

check in *manifest* file if `minSdkVersion` is **7** or **8** if it is greater than **10** then use `Activity` and `Fragment` from `android.app.Fragment`

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

And you have to add `appcompat v21` or `appcompat v7` library properly and use a `Theme` from that library you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Your Toolbar is on top of your fragment. Setting the found Toolbar view as ActionBar most likely causes another pass on layout which makes the fragment view disappear (most likely squashed under the Toolbar).

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/toolbar"
        android:align_parentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:align_parentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide me a solution?

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe see the updated answer. Set the Toolbar as actionbar before you place the fragment too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is solved, but it wasn't working for me.

So i will post my workaround. I simply disable the drawer indicator of the toolbar and enable it again. So the toolbar automatically shows the arrow. Try the following code in your onCreate(..)

```
   supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            int stackHeight = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (stackHeight > 0) {
                mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            } else {
                mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was using Toolbar, but I did not have a drawer or drawer indicator. I'm sure this will help others.